# character ASCII code in InstallScript InstallShield

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installscript, installscript-msi

I want to keep user from entering character > ASCII 127 in one of the password field in installer.

I googled but didn't find any direct way for this, currently i'm using:

```
CHAR ch;
STRING ASCII;
NUMBER nASCII;

for nCount = 0 to StrLength(sPassword)
  ch = sPassword[nCount];
  sprintf(ASCII,"%d",ch);

  StrToNum(nASCII,ASCII);

  if ( nASCII > 127 )
    MessageBox("Invalid Character in Password",INFORMATION);
  endif; 

endfor;
```

Is there any better way to get ASCII code from a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would avoid the conversion to and from string; just compare `sPassword[nCount]` with `127` directly; InstallScript stores wide chars (16-bit numbers).

As an alternative approach, you might try calling [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) with the US-ASCII [code page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (20127). I'm not that strong with InstallScript and am coding without the compiler, so you might have to fix an error or two, but here's the rough idea:

```
#define CP_US_ASCII 20127
extern prototype NUMBER Kernel32.WideCharToMultiByte(NUMBER, NUMBER, WSTRING, NUMBER, STRING, NUMBER, STRING, BYREF BOOL);

function BOOL IsSafeAscii(STRING szCheck)
    STRING szOut;
    BOOL bReplaced;
begin
    WideCharToMultiBute(CP_US_ASCII,          // only supports characters 0-127
                        WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS, // or maybe 0; disallow turning accented to plain
                        szCheck,              // test string
                        StrLength(szCheck),   // length of test string
                        szOut,                // return buffer
                        StrLength(szOut),     // length of return buffer
                        "?",                  // replacement for unsupported characters
                        bReplaced);           // whether replacement was used
    return !bReplaced;
end;
```